# Using grep to filter real time output of a process? If so, how to get the line after a match?

Tags: bash, process, grep, output, filtering

Should I use grep to filter a real time output? I'm not sure if this is what I should use for a real time output.

Example: `command -option | grep --color 'string1\|string2'`

If so, how to get also the lines after `string1` and `string2`?

Comment: what is a real time output?

Comment: Welcome DeborahAnn, it would be helpful if you clarify what you mean by real time output -- what exactly do you need grep to do? also, what exactly do you mean by getting the lines after? is this a single line after a match? or n lines? or every line after a `string1` or `string2` have been found?

Comment: Sorry, my english is bad. With "real time output" I mean a process who prints until is terminated by user (basically a loop).

Comment: Thanks @lucascaro. I have this text in output that is being generated by a process (this process is executed until the user decide to kill it) and I am using grep to find strings of this text that contains string1 or string 2.
Everytime string1 or string2 is found by grep I need to also print the line right after.
So if string1 is at line 20 and string2 is at line 80, I need to print line 21 and line 82.

Comment: check on `man grep` and see if your version offers the `-a` (lines **a**fter), so `cmd|grep -a2 's1\|s2'`. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter it should be upper case `A`, lowercase `a` means something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @shellter mentioned, from `man grep`:

```
 -A num, --after-context=num
         Print num lines of trailing context after each match.  See also the -B and -C options.
```

so you would use `command -option | grep -A 1 --color 'string1\|string2'` to print matched lines and the line right after them.

There are plenty of other options in the manual for grep, and most other command-line programs, so I suggest getting used to running `man cmd` as a quick first check.